# Flexipage deployment error

Tags: vs-code, xml, package.xml, flexipages

Error while deploying the flexipage in 21 sandbox ,, it is working fine by retrieving from the VS code
Kindly help

```
error: Property 'itemInstances' not valid in version 46.0
```

Comment: Im pretty sure you need to change your API to v49 for `itemInstances`.

Comment: I guess it's a version issue, try to retrieve using version 49 if you are retrieving from Summer 20 if you are retrieving from Winter 21 try with 50 version

Comment: How to change it can you help me out ??

Comment: I am just deploying from my VS code

Comment: If you are retrieving using package.xml then at the end you have version tag like <version>49.0</version>

Comment: Yes thats correct ...but how to deploy it ,, i am facing issue while deploying..back to sandbox

Comment: can you confirm what is  version of source org, target org & package.xml? https://youtu.be/m29Qi9pILoA  this video helps me for flexipage successful deployment

Comment: all are ate v 49

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify details of exactly how you retrieved and deployed the file. But it sounds like you retrieved with a newer API version (`itemInstances` was introduced in API 49) and deployed with an older API version (46.0). This would definitely cause an error.

Comment: can you please help me out how to fix this issue..i am not getting the root cause